# How to speed up my scissor function in python?

Tags: python, performance, data-preprocessing

I need a way to speed up my code. Feel free to use it :)

For a dataset of length 947 it takes 0.002 seconds to run the scissor (4hour data). For a dataset of length 4384 it takes 0.05 seconds (1hour data). A dataset of length 18132 takes 0.98 seconds (15min data). A dataset of length 54793 takes 19.67 seconds(5min data). A dataset of length 274761 takes 668.7 seconds.

While the scissor makes it possible for me to prepare the dataset once and then train my neural networks quite fast, I dont want to spend the rest of 2023 on getting the data. Knowing that I am in the test phase, I will probably have to rerun it a few times and if a quater of a million data points slow me down, you can imagine what happens when we reach a few million data points.

The code runs just fine, so it is a time problem more than a code problem. If you see any errors though, please let me know:

```
def scissor(scaled_data, scaled_dataframe, k):
    target_index = 20
    columns = scaled_dataframe.columns
    used_starting_points = []
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    y_train_index = []

    available_starting_points = set(range(2 * k - 1, len(scaled_data) - (k - 1)))

    while available_starting_points:
        available_starting_points = set(range(2 * k - 1, len(scaled_data) - (k - 1))) - set(used_starting_points)
        if not available_starting_points:
            break
        starting_point = random.choice(list(available_starting_points))
        window = scaled_data[starting_point - k: starting_point]

        target_value = scaled_data[starting_point, target_index]
        y_train_index.append(scaled_dataframe.index[starting_point + (k - 1)])

        x_train.append(window)
        y_train.append(target_value)

        used_starting_points.extend(range(starting_point - k, starting_point + k))
        overlapping_points = range(starting_point - k, starting_point + k)
        available_starting_points -= set(overlapping_points)

    x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), k * len(columns))
    y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(len(y_train), )

    return x_train, y_train, y_train_index
```

Comment: Doing `list(available_starting_points)` every iteration isn't going to be efficient.

Comment: Better use a profiler (e. g. https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/ ) first to find out what needs optimization most.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use NumPy Slicing: Instead of using a loop
2. Use Set Operations,
3. Preallocate NumPy Arrays: Instead of repeatedly appending to x_train and y_train
4. Avoid Extending Lists

   ```
   def scissor(scaled_data, scaled_dataframe, k):
       target_index = 20
       columns = scaled_dataframe.columns
       used_starting_points = set()
       x_train = []
       y_train = []
       y_train_index = []

       available_starting_points = set(range(2 * k - 1, len(scaled_data) - (k - 1)))

       while available_starting_points:
           starting_point = random.choice(list(available_starting_points))
           window = scaled_data[starting_point - k: starting_point]

           target_value = scaled_data[starting_point, target_index]
           y_train_index.append(scaled_dataframe.index[starting_point + (k - 1)])

           x_train.append(window.flatten())
           y_train.append(target_value)

           used_starting_points.update(range(starting_point - k, starting_point + k))
           overlapping_points = range(starting_point - k, starting_point + k)
           available_starting_points -= set(overlapping_points)

       x_train = np.array(x_train)
       y_train = np.array(y_train)

       return x_train, y_train, y_train_index
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the expensive list and set operations every iteration by using a list and popping indexes from it:

```
def scissor(scaled_data, scaled_dataframe, k):
    target_index = 20
    columns = scaled_dataframe.columns
    used_starting_points = []
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    y_train_index = []

    available_starting_points = list(range(2 * k - 1, len(scaled_data) - (k - 1)))

    while available_starting_points:
        starting_point_index = random.randint(0, len(available_starting_points))
        starting_point = available_starting_points.pop(starting_point_index)
        window = scaled_data[starting_point - k: starting_point]

        target_value = scaled_data[starting_point, target_index]
        y_train_index.append(scaled_dataframe.index[starting_point + (k - 1)])

        x_train.append(window)
        y_train.append(target_value)

    x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), k * len(columns))
    y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(len(y_train), )

    return x_train, y_train, y_train_index
```